# ASP.NET EF Database First 4.1 EDMX Extent1.XXX in fields list

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a MYSQL DB. I have user and address tables an more but the problem begins here. i have a web page. when i try to login it calls a webservice and goes to business class and executes following method to get user's address. i don't have any foreign keys for address and user tables

```
public IEnumerable<address> GetAddressByUserId(int UserId){
 try
 {
    using (var contex = new eTicaretEntity())
    {
      return contex.addresses.Where(x => x.UserId == UserId).ToList();
    }
 }
 catch (Exception exc)
 {
   throw exc;
 }
}
```

when it comes to the where part of the code it fails. and says:

> Unknown column 'Extent1.AddressType' in 'field list'

I'll put the links to the screenshots of tables in edmx file. there's no foreign keys between those two tables. and also there is a row recorded in address table with the userid that i pass to business. i see no reason why this happens.

Why am i seeing this error? how can i resolve it? is there anyone who can help? any help/thought appreciated.

Thanks.

[Address Table](http://bit.ly/1kmdfT0)
[User Table](http://bit.ly/1jx4CY0)

**EDIT**
i'm sorry if i tell this info late but i added addresstype to table after i created model. i mean i had table and edmx file which was perfectly fine. and then i added this column and updated edmx from db after that the problem has begun.

Comment: The database table has no `AddressType` field.

Comment: @GertArnold Did you see the links of screenshot images? i have AddressType column in my DB.

Comment: That's not the database, it's the class. I think the edmx was created off a different database.

Comment: What data type is AddressType?

Comment: @Mez Datatype of AddressType is integer.

Comment: @GertArnold it's not a different database. i checked app.config file it goes to my db.

Comment: Well, it's a database error anyhow. EF composes SQL with `Extent1.AddressType` in it and it's not found in the database table.

Comment: @GertArnold i'm sorry if i tell this info late but i added addresstype to table after i created model. i mean i had table and edmx file which was perfectly fine. and then i added this column and updated edmx from db after that the problem has begun. do you think it can cause the problem?. i edited my question

Comment: It must be related. Maybe you restored a database backup?

Answer (score 0):

Gert's Comment was correct, so here is a New try.

I have tested it With various combinations of removing Field from database, storeage model and conseptual model.

In no case did I get the same error as in the question. But I am using SQL Server.

"Extent1.AddressType" is from the SQL statement generated by EF. If the column was not in the database you would get a "Invalid column name : AddressType" error.

To find the error, import the table into a New EF model, check that it works, then compare the xml in the 2 models against each other.

Comment: This is not true. "Update model from database" updates both the storage model and the conceptual model as well as the mapping. Besides, the message clearly indicates that the models contain `AddressType`, but not the database. It's a MySql message and the `Extent1` prefix is from SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the edmx is generated with proper database, you should try update model from database by deleting only Address table from edmx.